# How to get/update data SPR32X60_SpreadSheet content using UIAutomation/IAccessibility/Win32API

Tags: winapi, ui-automation

We have a application having the object "SPR32X60_SpreadSheet". The object content are not available in inspect.exe. 
How can i get and take action on the content of SPR32X60_SpreadSheet grids using UIAutomation/IAccessibility/Win32API.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Preeti

Comment: Inspect.exe uses UI Automation. If it doesn't uncover automation interfaces, there aren't any for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Not all UI elements support UI Automation. For example, [custom SuperGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-support-for-standard-controls) doesn't support UI Automation.

Generally, most Win32 controls support UI Automation. Refer to [Supporting UI Automation Control Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-supportinguiautocontroltypes) for more detailed information.

To interact with an UI control that not support UI Automation, simulating mouse/keyboard input is a possible workaround. Refer to [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput).